# $\int \frac{dx}{a^2-x^2}=\frac{1}{2a}\ln\left|\frac{x+a}{x-a}\right|+C$

Tags: integration

> $\int\frac{dx}{a^2-x^2}=\frac{1}{2a}\ln\left|\frac{x+a}{x-a}\right|+C$

how to derive this formula?
$\int \frac{dx}{a^2-x^2}=\int\frac{dx}{(a-x)(a+x)}\boxed{=}\\\frac{1}{(a-x)(a+x)}=\frac{A}{a-x}+\frac{B}{a+x}\\1=A(x+a)+B(a-x)\\
x=a:1=A(a+a)\Rightarrow A=\frac{1}{2a}\\x=-a:1=B(a-(-a))=1=2aB\Rightarrow B=\frac{1}{2a}\\\frac{1}{(a+x)(a-x)}=\frac{\frac{1}{2a}}{a-x}+\frac{\frac{1}{2a}}{a+x}=\frac{1}{2a}\left(\frac{1}{a-x}+\frac{1}{a+x}\right)\\\int\frac{dx}{(a-x)(a+x)}=\int\frac{1}{2a}\left(\frac{1}{a-x}+\frac{1}{a+x}\right)dx=\frac{1}{2a}\left(\ln|a-x|\boxed{+}\ln|a+x|\right)=????$
where is mistake?

Comment: Be careful of your negatives: $\int\frac{1}{a-x}=-\ln(a-x)$!

Comment: It should be difference of the fractions not the addiition.

Comment: @JVV Thanks that's it...

Comment: @vmahth1 No problem. The fraction should also be swapped over :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beginning from your partial fractions:

\begin{align} \int{\frac{dx}{a^2-x^2}} &= \frac{1}{2a} \int{\frac{1}{a-x} + \frac{1}{a+x} \; dx} \\ &= \frac{1}{2a} \left(-\ln|a-x|+\ln|a+x|\right) + C \\ &= \frac{1}{2a} \; \ln\left|\frac{x+a}{x-a}\right| + C
\end{align}